# Printing raw data to TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have several variables, all strings or arrays, and I want to output them to TCPDF as raw data, which I can then position with SetXY.

Is there a way to pass just raw string data to TCPDF, without being HTML? All I'm seeing is WriteHTML()

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be doable with the text() function.